# PHP foreach print array with previous and next element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array $data and I want to print it with foreach ($data as $detail). Thing is that I want inside foreach to print previous and next element. Something like this:

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

// foreach result should look like this
8,1,2
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
6,7,8
7,8,1
```

Comment: what did you try to do? Please post the code who have tried. We will help to complete it

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Do you know how to use array indices?

Comment: also, please explain why in the first item, the previous item is refer to the last item in the array? (should not it be empty?) same problem on the last item

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Problem sloved thanks to Zrvan who didn't had additional questions. I'm trying to make jQuery carousel and previous and next element should be the links. I didn't have any code by now because I didn't knew how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go:

```
$data = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$count = count ($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $current)
{
  if (($key - 1) < 0)
  {
    $prev = $data[$count - 1];
  }
  else
  {
    $prev = $data[$key - 1];
  }

  if (($key + 1) > ($count - 1))
  {
    $next = $data[0];
  }
  else
  {
    $next = $data[$key + 1];
  }

echo $prev . ', ' . $current . ', ' . $next . "\n";
```

Or if brevity is an issue:

```
$count = count ($data);
foreach ($data as $i => $current)
{
  $prev = $data[(($i - 1) < 0) ? ($count - 1) : ($i - 1)];
  $next = $data[(($i + 1) > ($count - 1)) ? 0 : ($i + 1)];

  echo $prev . ',' . $current . ',' . $next . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This solution assumes an array with numeric index and no holes.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$count = count($data);

foreach($data as $index => $number)
{
  $previous = $data[($count+$index-1) % $count]; // '$count+...' avoids problems
                                                 // with modulo on negative numbers in PHP
  $current = $number;
  $next = $data[($index+1) % $count];

  echo $previous.", ".$current.", ".$next."\n";
}
```

About modulo on negative numbers: http://mindspill.net/computing/cross-platform-notes/php/php-modulo-operator-returns-negative-numbers.html

Answer (score 0):

Same result done differently:

```
<?php
$data = range(1,16);
$count=count($data);
$ret='';

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $ret.=($i==0)?$data[$count-1].',':$data[$i-1].',';
    $ret.=$data[$i].',';
    $ret.=($i+1>=$count)?$data[$count-$i-1]:$data[$i+1].'<br>';
}
echo $ret;
?>
Result:
16,1,2
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
6,7,8
7,8,9
8,9,10
9,10,11
10,11,12
11,12,13
12,13,14
13,14,15
14,15,16
15,16,1
```