# change position depending on DB value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

I let people fill in a form, and insert distances etc. They get stored in a db.

[image: after insert]

Then I lead them to a page, where I show the number of axles (12 in this case) and make a circle of them (in css)
Then it looks like this:

[image: What the page looks like]

The code for this:

```
<?php
        $show_axle = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
 ?>

    <div id="axle_bogie_border">
        <div id="axle_position">
            <?php      
                foreach($show_axle as $axlefigure){ ?>
                <div id='number_of_axles'> <?php echo $axlefigure['axle'] ?></div>
            <?php
                } 
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `axle_border` make the Train image (The black rectangle)

The `axle_position` take care that the axles (Numbers actually) Don't go in the image but slightly below it (So it looks like wheels/axles).

The `Number_of_axles` make the numbers look like a circle (Like wheels/axles).

Now the function:

```
function axles($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axle WHERE train_id = :id2";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":id2", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

The function selects everything from the table `axle` (See first image).

Now, I actually want the axles to take a position. And I'm thinking about doing that via the `Distance` row.

So:

Axle 1 has the number 5 for distance. So it goes 5px from the far left
Axle 2 has the number 10. So i want it 10 pixels next to the axle 1.
Axle 3 has the number 5. So i want it 5 pixels next to the axle 2.
Etc.

Eventually it needs to look like this:

[image: How it should look]

My question: Is this posible. If yes, how?

***EDIT:***

it is working now :) 
I did the following:

```
<?php
        $show_axle = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
?>
    <div id="axle_bogie_border">
        <div id="axle_position2">
            <?php      
                foreach($show_axle as $axlefigure){ ?>
                    <div style="margin-left:<?php echo $axlefigure['distance'];?>px;"> 
                        <?php echo $axlefigure['axle'] ?>
                    </div>
            <?php
                } 
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
#axle_position2 {
    margin-top: 9%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}



#axle_position2 div {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    position: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Could you do an inline `style: margin-left: <? echo $axleFigure['distance'];?>px` ?

Comment: i did: <style>
     number_of_axles{margin-left: <? echo $axleFigure['distance'];?>px}
    </style> tough it does nothing atm

Comment: You can position it with distance as left. You can calculate the `left` by adding distance of current element and previous elements distance. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sak6up6g/)

Comment: Got this: <div id="axle_position">
         <?php      
                foreach($show_axle as $axlefigure){ ?>
                <div id='number_of_axles'><div style="left:<?php echo $axlefigure['distance'];?>px"> <?php echo $axlefigure['axle'] ?></div></div>
            <?php
                } 
            ?>
        </div> Does nothing :(

Comment: Did you add the CSS also like in the fiddle? As left works only with positioned elements.

Comment: i did this: #number_of_axles  div. It works with this :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay, i have 1 problem. It works, but not the right way haha. I want the axles to already automatically be next to eachother instead of in eachother. Because the distance between axle 1 and 2 is maybi 5px. And the distance between axle 3 and 4 aswell. But right now, for example: The axles 4 goes back to axle 2. But i actually want them to push to the right instead of going into eachother. How do i do this?? @anpsmn

Comment: You need to add the distances of previous element something like `left = current_elem[distance] + prev_elem[distance]`

Comment: Like this: <div style="left:<?php echo $axlefigure['distance']; + $axlefigure['distance'];?>   ??? Because it still looks the same if i do this (Only everything goes a little to the left. (Start of loop i think)

Comment: No, in the above method you will get same distance. You need to have an index pointing to the value such that you can use distance of current index and distance of previous index i.e (index-1)

Comment: Hmmm i understand, but don't know how to do that in a loop... Can you give a little example in a fiddle???

Comment: @Mitch fiddle check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255520/php-foreach-print-array-with-previous-and-next-element